# Aligning expressions below a limit

Tags: horizontal-alignment, math-operators

I need the operator `\Lim` to be placed on the left, so it could be aligned with the expression wrote below it (`(x \rightarrow a)^{+}`). Please see the screenshot provided for a reference.

How could I get it?

[image]

Comment: `\[\lim_{(x\to a)^{-}} f(x)  = L\]`?

Comment: Do you want "Lim" or "lim"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your alignment can be forced using some overlaps and `\phantom`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \mathop{\mathrlap{\textit{Lim}}\phantom{\scriptstyle (x \to a)^-}}_{(x \to a)^-} f(x) &= L \\ % (1)
  \lim_{(x \to a)^-} f(x) &= L % (2)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I'd stick with the second style though, since it's what is used more widely (and the first doesn't add any more value).

Comment: The first solution will go straight in my gallery of horrors.

Comment: @egreg: You should show that one day! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you load the `amsmath` package and use its `\DeclareMathOperator*` macro to create a macro called `\Lim` -- is the uppercase-L deliberate, by the way? -- that places its argument *below* the string "Lim" in display-style math mode. Note that it's customary to use upright rather than italic letters for math operators. (Cf. also "sin", "cos", "log", "det", etc.)

Incidentally, the macro `\lim` is predefined in PlainTeX and in LaTeX. I'm not sure it's a good idea to define `\Lim` as well -- unless, of course, `\lim` and `\Lim` are supposed to denote different things.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Lim}{Lim}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \Lim_{(x\to a)^-} f(x)=L$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I used \DeclareMathOperator* to set "Lim" instead "lim", also I put it on Italic. My problem isn't this matter but the ilignment showed on the screenshot i've posted.

Comment: @AdN You mean that this is what you want? `\Lim_{\hphantom{^-}(x\to a)^-} f(x) = L`? If not, please, clarify what alignment are you looking for.